# Replace all \ with \\ - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with replacing all the occurences of a slash inside my string to a double-slash. Right now this problem is preventing me from opening a file, thus I need to "escape" all the slashes in my path.

The path looks something like this:

```
C:\Folder\tmp\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1
```

I want to replace all the slashes to double slashes, so that in the end it would look like this:

```
C:\\Folder\\tmp\\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1
```

I already tried using this solution but it doesn't work for me:

```
str.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

The output of the solution above produces the following string:

```
C:Folder    mpc235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1
```

**EDIT** This is the actual code where I'm trying to solve the problem:

```
exports.register = function (req, res) {
    let user = new db.User();

    req.files.forEach(function(file) {
        const uploadDir = 'upload/' + user._id + '/' + file.name;
        const filePath = path.resolve('./' + file.path);

        console.log(filePath);
        ftp.put(filePath, uploadDir, function(err) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);

            console.log('Uploaded file: ' + file.name);
        });
    });
};
```

I omitted irrelevant parts

Comment: You need to post your actual code. Where are you pulling this path from? is it in a variable? from an API?

Comment: @Marie I'm doing `path.resolve` in order to get path of the project.

Comment: Can you include the code in your question? If we dont see a functional example the best we can do is guess.

Comment: When you `console.log(filePath);` what do you get in the console?

Comment: @BrianLeishman I get the following path 
`c:\Folder\tmp\8f45671adc937209de5d826dbf1bc31a
`

Comment: @DavidLasry is your `err` log being hit? And Just FYI there is a `console.error` method you can use to make errors more visible.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character is an escape character in a JavaScript string literal. It doesn't exist in the string.

You can't use a regular expression to fix your problem because it is the *source code* you need to change, not the data in the string itself.

By the time you get the string, the `\` characters will have been parsed and (for example) `\t` turned into a tab. At this point it is **too late** to manipulate the data to get the actual directory path back.

Comment: Let's say for the sake of argument that the path with single backslashes is not actually in Javascript source code, but within a string literal.  Does your logic still apply?

Comment: @RobertHarvey — A "string literal" is something that only exists in the source code. It is JavaScript syntax. So that argument doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So it's literally impossible to create a string literal in Javascript that contains a backslash?  I find that improbable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey — I never claimed that. As I said in the second paragraph, the source code needs changing to fix the problem. You can't escape a slash in a string after the slash has already been consumed by the JavaScript parser. The OP said "The output of the solution above produces the following string" - but they would get the same result if they didn't try to manipulate it at all. There are no slashes in the string. Only in the source code.

Comment: But the string could already exist in a Javascript variable, yes?  You're making quite a few assumptions here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey — If the string, in the JS variable, had slashes in it, then the OP would not get the result they get. The slashes must therefore exist only in the source code (where they are treated as escape characters).

Comment: OK, I see that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That the result is `C:Folder    mpc235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1` can only happen, if the `\t` was already transformed to a tab before `replace` was called. For the given output there is no way that the backslashes existed as such in `str`.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is hard coded in your JavaScript, then your escaping the characters in that string unless you escape the escape characters (`\\`). Try just a console output of that string as you have it

```
console.log('C:\Folder\tmp\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1');
// outputs "C:Folder    mpc235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1"
```

So the replacement for the slashes isn't replacing anything because there isn't actually any slashes in it.

```
'C:\\Folder\\tmp\\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1'.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
```

Running something like that above outputs exactly what you're looking for.

To elaborate a bit, that gap between `C:Folder` and `mpc235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1` is there because `\t` is the tab character, and that space is a tab. The `c` is still there after `mp` because `\c` isn't anything, it's not an escape sequence.

If you got this text from a different source (not hard coded in the JS), then you wouldn't need to worry about this and your `str.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");` would work as expected.

```
var Path = 'C:\\Folder\\tmp\\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1';
console.log(Path);
console.log(Path.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'))
console.log(Path.replace(/\\/g, '/'))

//VM2431:2 C:\Folder\tmp\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1
//VM2431:3 C:\\Folder\\tmp\\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1
//VM2431:4 C:/Folder/tmp/c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#raw.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```
String.raw`C:\Folder\tmp\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1`
```

Output:

```
"C:\\Folder\\tmp\\c235adf5b8c79ee61910a0c04abf9bc1"
```

Comment: The OP does not appear to understand escape characters at all. This is a band-aid of a recommendation at best.